# Using a User defined table type with a temporary stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having trouble using a user defined table type as a parameter type to a temporary stored procedure.

I am doing all of this within the database that houses our temp tables, temp stored procedures,... temp anything.

The code looks like this:

```
CREATE TYPE test_type AS TABLE (user int, user_value int) 
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE #test_pro 
    @input test_type READONLY
AS
    SELECT TOP 10 * 
    FROM @input 
GO
```

I get the error:

> Parameter or variable @input has an invalid data type.

Is there a way for me to use the data type `test_type` as a type in my temporary stored procedure? I unfortunately only have access to temporary stored procedures and not the permanent version.

Side question: would using a function work any better?

Comment: Have you tried creating the user defined type in `tempdb`?

Comment: How would I do that? That sounds like where I am already as I mentioned I’m in the DB where our temp tables are stored

Comment: I suggest you rethink the idea of using temp procedures. It is a rarely used feature.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create the UDT in `tempdb`.

The following works fine

```
USE tempdb

GO

CREATE TYPE test_type AS TABLE ([user] int, user_value int)

GO

--Switch database
USE msdb

GO

CREATE PROCEDURE #test_pro @input TEST_TYPE READONLY
AS
    SELECT TOP 10 *
    FROM   @input

GO

EXEC #test_pro

GO

USE tempdb

DROP TYPE test_type

DROP PROC #test_pro
```

If you don't have `CREATE TYPE` permissions in `tempdb` you can potentially use a `#temp` table instead.

e.g. the following works

```
CREATE PROCEDURE #test_pro 
AS
    SELECT TOP 10 * 
    FROM #input 
GO

GO

CREATE TABLE #input([user] int, user_value int) 

GO

EXEC #test_pro
```

Comment: I do not have the create type permission in tempdb. I'm aware that I could declare my tables outside the stored procedure, but I was hoping to avoid that in order to keep the code base much more compartmentalized with just functions/stored procedures... would using user define functions make any of this any more doable?

Comment: @H_1317 - I have no idea what permissions you have and what constraints you are working under. I assume you don't have permissions to create regular procs (hence use of `#temp` proc)? so why would you have permissions to create functions? Or if you do have `CREATE PROC` permissions to create regular procs then you can just create one in the same database as the type and you are done.

Comment: I admit it was a hail mary. thank you for the help though. will have to contact my admin.